# MySQL Process List - locked issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

In the MySQL Process List, it is showing a few `SELECT` query has been locked. Time of locked show over 4000

```
|   24 | user | localhost | database | Query   | 4725 | Locked   | SELECT * FROM data  
|   25 | user | localhost | database | Query   | 4725 | Locked   | SELECT * FROM data
|   26 | user | localhost | database | Query   | 4725 | Locked   | SELECT * FROM data
```

PHP Script has been executed a few time but then `SELECT` became in Locked state.  How to solve this problem?

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM data";
$query = $db->prepare($SQL);
$query->execute();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //Do something
    sleep(2);
}
```

Is mySQL server limiting SELECT query to run once at the time? can this be changed?

Answer (score 3):

You should run `show engine innodb status \G` to see what query is holding that lock.

After discussion this in comments and hearing that MyISAM is in use and that there are alot of writes I'm suggestion you move to InnoDB.

InnoDB has been the default engine for a while and is normally better. In this case you will get row based locking. InnoDB is also being developed more than MyISAM.

Comment: MyISAM locks the entire table when it does writes and no reads can be done until that lock is released. There are some rules about how many reads can be executed before a write gets access and so on but in your case it definitely looks like there is a write blocking your reads.

Comment: Yes it is doing a lot and a lot of write to update the status, eg: `UPDATE data SET status = 1 WHERE field = x`, so im not sure what do I need to do now? if i change it to innodb would that fix a problem?

Comment: You can disregard my answer then. A first solution would be to handle more updates with `field in (x,y,z...)` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have select statements in your process list, this is likely caused by limited available resources on your server. If that's the case, you can avoid the problem by trying to optimize the queries that are run if possible, or try implementing some kind of caching on the server. You can also lower the max_connections system variable, but that might not be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

How large is your tables?

INNODB is not a magic. some information about the system can help.

Comment: over 140,000 rows...  First used a `SELECT` query and then do a lot `UPDATE`. Server spec is: Intel Core 2 Quad Q8300, 4GB, Linux.   MySQL Server CPU 100% high

Comment: SELECT * FROM 140K rows? I can understand why it slow and heavy.

Comment: also, what is your MySQL version?